# Redirecting URLs on an Apache Server

Tags: apache, redirect

Here's what I need to do...

**What I have:**

I have 1 public IP address and 2 internal web servers.

Both internal servers are Ubuntu server 22.04

Public IP = 192.168.0.2 serving ports 80,443 to the public (obviously 192.168.1.2 is not my real public IP address)

Internal web server 1 = 10.0.0.200 serving ports 80,443 (Ubuntu 22.04 LAMP server running 3 Apache2 web sites using vhost for [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com), [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com), [www.domain3.com](http://www.domain3.com))

Internal web server 2 = 10.0.0.201 serving ports 80,443 (Ubuntu 22.04 with a docker container running [www.domain4.com](http://www.domain4.com) on a Caddy 2 web server)

**What needs to happen:**

I need internal Apache web server 1 at 10.0.0.200 to forward request for [www.domain4.com](http://www.domain4.com) to internal Caddy web server at 10.0.0.201 port 443

I haven't tried any solutions as of yet. Looking for recommendations on how to make this happen.